# Pidgin service ends when closing buddy list

Tags: services, pidgin

For those who don't know what Pidgin is: learn, it's the greatest chat client I've ever used.

On launching it opens the buddy list, and everything works like normal, but the tray icon isn't showing up and when I close the buddy list it also closes all the chat windows and ends the service.

Any advice on how to fix Pidgin? Or how to solve problems similar to this in general? I'm not too experienced but I'll try to provide as much info as I can. Thanks in advance